# React-native-navigation (wix) how to skip route

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have 3 screens

ScreenA,
ScreenB,
ScreenC

Routes

1. ScreenA->ScreenB, ScreenB-back->ScreenA
2. ScreenA->ScreenC, ScreenC-back->ScreenA
3. ScreenA->ScreenB->ScreenC

My question is regarding 3rd route, when user is on ScreenC and he/she pressed backbutton/backnavbarbutton ScreenA will be shown instead of Screen B

**Environment**

**React Native Navigation version**: 1.1.431

**React Native version**: 0.54.4

**Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?)**: iOS

Comment: Please adapt your tags to use `wixcode` as `wix` means `Windows Installer XML`.

Comment: done, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setOnNavigatorEvent` or the `addOnNavigatorEvent` which will replace the existing navigator for custom handling of back button..
so in your constructor

```
class ScreenC extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(
      this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this)
    );
  }

  ...

  onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    switch (event.id) {
      case 'backPress':
        ... what ever you want

    }
  }

  ... rest of your code
}
```

You can read more about them [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=setonnavigatoreventcallback)

Comment: no i cant do what ever i want, the solution you are suggesting is good if i want to push the ScreenA on backPress, but it will lead me to another problem, now from on ScreenA if someone press back it will pop to screenC which is incorrect. i hope you understand what i said